# Task.Json triggers validation on invisible only fields

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to create a Azure DevOps Pipelines Custom extension. I have a task.json where fields are visible on certain conditions.

For example:

```
 {
  "name": "actions",
  "type": "picklist",
  "label": "Actions",
  "defaultValue": "Select",
  "required": true,
  "helpMarkDown": "Select an Action from the dropdown as per your requirement.",
  "options": {
    "New": "Add",
    "Delete": "Delete"
  }
},

{
  "name": "backEndIPAddress",
  "type": "string",
  "label": "IP Address",
  "required": true,
  "defaultValue": "",
  "helpMarkDown": "",
  "visibleRule": "actions = New",
  "validation": {
    "expression": "isMatch(value,'^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?){0,15}$','IgnoreCase')",
    "message": "Invalid IP Address. Please try again!"
  }
}
```

The issue when the IPAddress field is hidden, the validation is still tried and it fails. How to ensure that the fields are validated only if they are visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options:

- Set a default value for the input
- Update the regex to include `^$|` at the start to allow empty values (`'require':true` will take care of the requiredness)

Remember that there should be a default `isIpV4Address(value: string)` function so you don't have to specify the regex.

From the docs it looks like there is an upcoming `when` clause which will dictate when the set of rules should trigger, I suppose this may be causing the currently unwanted behavior.

See also:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/1d75fa8f66aa1cf7a9cb62946939f30f087b2969/docs/taskinputvalidation.md

Comment: Since I could not use default value, I went with the regex change. The issue with using isIpV4Address is that it again checks for empty and throws error.